# HTML pass form inputs to javascript and reset form fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script

I am creating a form in HTML and then passing the input fields as a form object to javascript. I want my program to then reset all the input fields except one (`name`) after it has passed the object to JS, but it appears the fields are reset before they get passed to JS.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      // Prevent form from submitting
      function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

      function FormSubmit(formObject) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(FormSuccess()).EnterData(formObject); 
      }
      function FormSuccess() {
        var resets = document.getElementsByClassName("reset");
        for (var i = 0; i < resets.length; i++) {
          resets[i].value = "";
        }

        google.script.run.ProgramSuccess();
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="entryForm" onsubmit="FormSubmit(this)">
      Name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <br>
      Client Name:<br>
      <input class = "reset" type="text" name="clientName">
      <br>
      Project Type:<br>
      <input class = "reset" type="text" name="projectType">
      <br>
      Task:<br>
      <input class = "reset" type="text" name="task">
      <br>
      Hours:<br>
      <input class = "reset" type="number" name="hours" min="0">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      <input type="reset">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
function EnterData(fObject) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.activate();

  var entries = [[fObject.name, fObject.clientName, fObject.projectType, fObject.task, fObject.hours]];
  var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 2, 1, 5);
  range.setValues(entries);


  return;
}

function ProgramSuccess() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.toast("Program Run Complete");
}
```

Am I using the `withSuccessHandler` incorrectly? Or is there a different way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: `withSuccessHandler(FormSuccess)` remove the `()`. The handler is looking for a reference to the function.

Comment: @SpencerEaston Thanks you, that worked perfectly. But could you explain a little more why? I would assume you need the `()` to specify that you are running a function and not just passing some type of variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The withSuccessHandler method accepts a function as its callback parameter.

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)

In your code `withSuccessHandler(FormSuccess())` will invoke the FormSuccess method. FormSuccess has no return value so in actuality you calling `withSuccessHandler(null)`.  By removing the `()` you are passing the reference to the function instead of invoking the function. `withSuccessHandler` will invoke the function itself using the reference you gave it adding the return value of the server side function you called as the first parameter.